# It is possible to force browser to not cache returned image through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, browser, browser-cache

So, I have a web page which has a link to a URL, which if clicked, returns an image. The web server is running Flask. On call of that URL, Flask fetches a new image each time to return to the client.

However, due to the Browser caching the image, the user don't see the new image, if the link is clicked the second time. The only way to see the new image is to clear the Browser cache, or open the link in Private/Incognito mode.

So, I was wondering, if through some Javascript trick, I can force the browser to not cache the image, that is, get the new image each time.

Comment: Set appropriate HTTP headers from the server that instruct the browser not cache the response.

Comment: Yes, add at the end of your image url some version/timestamp: <img src="http://yourimageurl.com/myimage.png?v=[timestamp/version]">